# Empty subobject optimization

Tags: c++

I ran across the 1997 article, [*The "Empty Member" C++ Optimization*](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html) by Nathan C. Meyers which discusses methods to "stash" empty objects like STL allocators as a base class of a member structure. He mentions in passing at the very end:

> Update again: A whole family of related "empty subobject" optimizations are possible, subject to the ABI specifications a compiler must observe. (Jason Merrill pointed some of these out to me, years back.) For example, consider three struct members of (empty) types A, B, and C, and a fourth non-empty. They may, conformingly, all occupy the same address, as long as they don't have any bases in common with one another or with the containing class. A common gotcha in practice is to have the first (or only) member of a class derived from the same empty base as the class. The compiler has to insert padding so that they two subobjects have different addresses. This actually occurs in iterator adapters that have an interator member, both derived from std::iterator. An incautiously-implemented standard std::reverse_iterator might exhibit this problem.

**Can someone describe this in a concrete example?** I'm missing something. [Here's what I tried in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/gttYyX):

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct {} nothing;
    int16_t x;
    int16_t y;
} STRUCT_C;

typedef struct
{
    struct {} nothing_a;
    struct {} nothing_b;
    int16_t x;
    int16_t y;
} STRUCT_D;

typedef struct {} NOTHING_A;
typedef struct {} NOTHING_B;

typedef struct
{
    struct M : public NOTHING_A, NOTHING_B {
        int16_t x;
    } m;
    int16_t y;
} STRUCT_E;

int doit3(STRUCT_C *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->x;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}

int doit4(STRUCT_D *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->x;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}

int doit4a(STRUCT_D *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->nothing_a;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}

int doit4b(STRUCT_D *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->nothing_b;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}

int doit5a(STRUCT_E *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->m.x;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}

int doit5b(STRUCT_E *p)
{
    void *addr1 = p;
    void *addr2 = &p->y;
    return (int)((uint8_t *)addr2 - (uint8_t *)addr1);
}
```

which produce both from clang 10.0.0 and gcc 9.3 (the `xor eax, eax` produces 0 on x86-64):

```
doit3(STRUCT_C*):
        mov     eax, 2
        ret
doit4(STRUCT_D*):
        mov     eax, 2
        ret
doit4a(STRUCT_D*):
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
doit4b(STRUCT_D*):
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
doit5a(STRUCT_E*):
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
doit5b(STRUCT_E*):
        mov     eax, 2
        ret
```

which reflect my understanding of the C++ standard, namely that the empty base class optimization allows the compiler to allocate no space for empty base classes, but all member objects need at least 1 byte of space to ensure they have unique addresses. (And the compiler has alignment constraints as in `STRUCT_C` where the `nothing` member only needs 1 byte but the offset for `x` is 2 bytes)

What is Nathan Meyers trying to suggest in his "update" ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand him, in your case that means that all `nothing_a`, `nothing_b` and `x` could have the same address since both `nothing_a` and `nothing_b` are empty and has no common base classes, so no two separate objects of the same type would have the same address.

Comment: That's what I thought I read, but it doesn't jive with my understanding of the C++ standard, and neither clang nor gcc can be used to demonstrate it.

Comment: C++ standard doesn’t explicitly allow such optimization AFAIK, so no compiler should do that (MSVC could ofc). But as I see it, the key point is that while pointers to different objects must be different, when the objects have different types the pointers are different by definition (a.k.a. aliasing rules) regardless of actual values.